# JavaScript , CSS and AngularJS mixup challenge

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to use a mini-app to calculate the maximum width (in pixels) of a certain String. I want to show the String truncated to the last word allowed (something like 'Lorem ipsum ...' ).

I have the data of the String width and the number of characters. Problem is, sometimes I get a really long String so I can't use the lastIndexOf(" ") to clip that string.

Is there a way to get the maximum of characters using CSS or some other solution? (font size and font family already fixed)

Comment: Do you want to truncate the text when it goes beyond the `div` or other elements width?

Comment: I have the text enclosed in a span that adjusts to the text inside. I want to truncate it when the width of that span is greater than 457px

Answer (score 0):

use below css property

`text-overflow: ellipsis;`

[Reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)